# Random "Unable to locate credentials" in the child processes on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, shell, asynchronous, amazon-linux-2

## Bounty clarification

I already found band-aid solution, see my answer.

However, I still do not understand

1. At what point script below is throttled - when it calls IMDS? or when IMDS calls STS?
2. Why passing credentials from parent process to children did not help? It seems like throttling happens not at credentials request but at some later stage, smth like "verify credentials passed through env variables" or whatever.

Bounty will be awarded for the answering of any of these two questions, reference to the docs/source code are appreciated.

**Please do not suggest rewrite in Python or any other cool language, it is out of the scope in this question**

## Original question

I have an AWS EC2 host with 96 vCPUs

I execute following script which spans async child processes up to a certain limit (passed as a script param). Each async child process calls AWS CLI and exits

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function f() {
 p=$1
 echo "$(date) entering f($p)"
 aws sts get-caller-identity
 echo "$(date) leaving f($p)"
}

a=""
for i in {1..400}; do
  a="$a
  $i"
done

jobs_limit=$1

while read line; do
    jobs=$(jobs -r | wc -l)
    while [ $jobs -ge $jobs_limit ]; do
      sleep 0.1
      jobs=$(jobs -r | wc -l)
    done
    echo "$(f $line)" &
done < <(echo "$a")

wait
```

**Problem:** when there are more than 40 child processes, then **some** processes randomly get `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".` error.

Here is output when script is executed with different limits

```
sh-4.2$ /tmp/b.sh 40 2>&1 | egrep 'Unable to locate credentials' | wc -l
0

sh-4.2$ /tmp/b.sh 40 2>&1 | egrep 'Unable to locate credentials' | wc -l
0

sh-4.2$ /tmp/b.sh 44 2>&1 | egrep 'Unable to locate credentials' | wc -l
22

sh-4.2$ /tmp/b.sh 44 2>&1 | egrep 'Unable to locate credentials' | wc -l
7

sh-4.2$ /tmp/b.sh 48 2>&1 | egrep 'Unable to locate credentials' | wc -l
18

sh-4.2$ /tmp/b.sh 48 2>&1 | egrep 'Unable to locate credentials' | wc -l
14
```

As you see above, zero errors for 40, random number of errors when more than 40.

Can someone explain what's going on?

---

Had an idea that it may be calling `/metadata` endpoint to get creds and it limits somehow requests rate, so I changed to get creds in parent process and pass these to child but no luck

```
function f() {
 p=$1
 cc=$2
 echo "$(date) entering f($p)"
  k=$(echo $cc | jq .AccessKeyId -r)
  s=$(echo $cc | jq .SecretAccessKey -r)
  t=$(echo $cc | jq .Token -r)
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$k AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$t aws sts get-caller-identity
 echo "$(date) leaving f($p)"
}

...

creds=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EMRJobFlowRole)

...

   echo "$(f $line $creds)" &

...
```

Comment: Can I ask... _WHY_ are you wanting to do this?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to connect from EMR master host to all core nodes and do not want to do it sequentially. Anyway, as a last resort I can do sequentially. However, at this point I'm just curious what's going on? Why child processes randomly cannot find creds?

Comment: Using a 96 vCPU instance is a bit of overkill and costs $5+ per hour. Rather than worrying about why a fictional scenario is misbehaving, you should probably concentrate on achieving what you actually want to do. What do you want to do on each worker node? For your situation, it might be better to write your own Python script rather than calling the AWS CLI.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  96 vCPUs is just a context, it was not created that big for calling AWS CLI. Yes, Python is an option but still want to understand what's going on

Comment: The IMDS will certainly [throttle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#instancedata-throttling) your requests: "avoid querying for credentials during every transaction or concurrently from a high number of threads or processes".

Comment: @jarmod I got error if query `/metadata` endpoint just one time from parent process, see 2nd part of my question

Comment: When run when the IMDS endpoint available, the AWS CLI will always make at least two requests, one to get a token, and one to determine the az.  If it can't find a local credential, then it'll fall back to calling the IMDS endpoint for credentials as well.  So, you're going to hit the 5 request per second limit if you spawn 90 instances of AWS at once.  In other words:  Don't do that.

Comment: @AnonCoward I'm pretty sure I'm doing more than 5 per second with no problem, see my answer. How do I provide AZ info to the script so it does not call IMDS?

Comment: The limit is a little fuzzy, so you might be able to get away with more.  At any rate, I know of no way to prevent the CLI from calling the IMDS service.  You might be able to disable it all together with something like `aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options --instance-id i-whatever --http-endpoint disabled`, though I have no idea if that would have follow on problems.

Comment: Can you try to put `export AWS_METADATA_SERVICE_NUM_ATTEMPTS=10` at the beginning of the script to see if it has any effects ?

Answer (score 0):

@jarmod pointed me to right direction. If I reduce the rate at which I span children, then problem goes away.

See extra `sleep 0.050` at the end of the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

function f() {
 p=$1
 echo "$(date) entering f($p)"
 aws sts get-caller-identity
 echo "$(date) leaving f($p)"
}

a=""
for i in {1..400}; do
  a="$a
  $i"
done

jobs_limit=$1

while read line; do
    jobs=$(jobs -r | wc -l)
    while [ $jobs -ge $jobs_limit ]; do
      sleep 0.050
      jobs=$(jobs -r | wc -l)
    done
    echo "$(f $line)" &

    # Otherwise IMDS throttles us
    sleep 0.05

done < <(echo "$a")

wait
```

---

Still open question: if it is IMDS related issue, then why it does not work when I pass credentials to every child process? Why does it call IMDS in this scenario?

Comment: Answering your own bountied question is IMO cringe - should offer @jarmod to write it up so you can accept.   But since I'm here - your bash is dirty, before I would even tackle it id clean it up: the one character vars and functions are impossible to work with .  Also why create `$a` if you already know how to iterate 1..400?    Whats the point of putting the echos in the bg?  *I THINK* the `$(f $line)` evaluates lin the foreground end only the echo then gets sent to the background but would finish quite instantaneously.  Make `f` do what you really want end drop the echo.

Comment: I answered well before bounty